# Android Internal Storage why default private

Tags: android

I am confusing about little part of this documentation --http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal--

It says :
You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user).

But in write operation i assign it like that : (Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

I can also assign it readable or writable.

Is there any intention in this documentation paraghraph that i cannot notice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the mostly safe mode to use is `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` since the other modes are deprecated in API Level 17 as mentioned in [Reference API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE).
It is recommended to use something like Content Provider if you want to use this data outside your application.